# Getting Error: [$injector:unpr] error in angularjs but i have added my dependencies correcty?

Tags: angularjs

**this is how my  factory looks like**

```
app.factory('AuthenticationService',['$http', function ($http, $localStorage) {

    var AuthenticationService =  {};
    var api = 'http://del1-vm-kohls:8080/Survey' ;


     AuthenticationService.Login = function(username,password,callback){

         $http.post('http://del1-vm-kohls:8080/Survey/user/login',{userId: username, password: password})
            .success(function(response){
                 if(response.token) {
                     // storing token in localstorage if user refreshes 
                     $localStorage.currentUser = {userId : username , token: response.token };

                     // adding token of authentication for futher use in getting data
                     authentication.token = response.token;

                     callback(true);
                 }
                 else{
                     callback(false);
                 }
         });
     }

     AuthenticationService.getSurvey = function(token){

     }

     return AuthenticationService;
}]);
```

**this is how my controller looks like**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$http', 'AuthenticationService', function($scope, $localStorage, $http, AuthenticationService){

    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.login = false;

    $scope.checkLogin = function(){

       AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(result){
          if(result === true)
              {
                  console.login("Logindone");
                  $scope.login = true;
                  $localStorage.setItem('auth', 'true');
                  location.href = "../../application/content/index.html";

              }
           else{
                   $scope.login = false;
                   $localStorage.setItem('auth', 'false');
                   sweetAlert("", "Invalid Username or Password", "error");
           }
       });           
    }    

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$localStorage` in factory dependency declaration.

It should be like :

```
app.factory('AuthenticationService',['$http','$localStorage', function ($http, $localStorage) {
```

Comment: @abhishekgangwar: what's not working,? if you have same error check if all all dependencies loaded in your `html` correctly in right order ? or now you have some other error ? and what is `authentication.token` in your `factory method`?

Comment: i am having same error as before. i have checked the order of dependencies as well. and as far as authentication.token is concerned , i was trying to assing token to a key to object AuthenticationService. so basically its AuthenticationService.token.

Comment: I don't see where you inject or defined `authentication` in factory ?, try to run by commenting `authentication.token = response.token;`

Comment: Error looks like this may be you can relate now.             
angular.js:12416 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthenticationServiceProvider%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService%20%3C-%20myCtrl
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4284
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4432)
    at angular.js:4289
    at d (angular.js:4432)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4464)
    at Q.instance (angular.js:9093)
    at L (angular.js:8205)
    at g (angular.js:7637)
    at angular.js:7512

Comment: @abhishekgangwar: I guess you used, `ngStorage` which is external lib., so you have to include it in module declaration as well. like : `angular.module('app', [ 'ngStorage' ]).`

Comment: No i am not using ngStorage

Comment: then what is `$localStorage` ?

Comment: Hi I was having some other error so it was not able to find my service. Thanx for your support.